# Double conversion string

Tags: c, string

I have the following code:

```
FILE *fp;
double Data[9][7];
int i=0,k;                  
fp = fopen ( "dstest 2.mod", "r" ) ;
fscanf(fp, "%E %E %E %E %E %E %E*[ ]",
           &Data[i][0],
           &Data[i][1],
           &Data[i][2],
           &Data[i][3],
           &Data[i][4],
           &Data[i][5],
           &Data[i][6] );
```

But whenever I run it I get the following warnings:

Read.c:12: warning: format ‘%E’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’

And it goes for all the arguments (Data[i][j]). I have no idea what's wrong. The problem goes away when I use float Data instead of double data. But that will not fit in my requirements.

Comment: You get that warning when you compile it, not when you run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man scanf says that you need the `l` modifier character to read a double:

```
fscanf(fp, "%lE %lE...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%lE` to specify a `double` instead of a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

`%E` works with `float`s; for `double`s you have to use `%lE`.

Sadly, inconsistency between the `printf` and the `scanf` here is not helping (`printf` does not support `float`s since all variadic arguments of type `float` are implicitly converted to `double`, but `scanf` does make a difference between the two FP types)